# Async task reports wrong execution progress with firebase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am uploading SMS messages to firebase using async task, but asyn task executes onProgressUpdate method instantly, it's not reporting the real progress as how many items are inserted to firebase. I want to show the real progress as the messages are uploaded. The Asyn task completes instantly, but the messages were still adding in the firebase console. How can I get the real progress.

Code:

```
 private class UploadConversations extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
        mBuilder.setProgress(totalMsgs, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // Update progress
        mBuilder.setProgress(totalMsgs, values[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Looping for the messages
               while(i < totalMsgs)
               {
                //Upload
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                //Log.v(LOGTAG, "Uploading chat id: " + item.getId());
                String msgID = _id + "";
                myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).child("_id").setValue(_id);
                myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).child("type").setValue(type);
                myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).child("message").setValue(body); //body
                myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).child("time").setValue(dateFormat.format(timestamp));
                myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).child("time_stamp").setValue(timestamp); //Date


                i++;
                publishProgress(i);




            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(LOGTAG, ex.getMessage());

        }
        finally {  cur.close();}

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Uploaded");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Backup completed");
        // Removes the progress bar
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

        mNotifyManager.cancel(id);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Database client already runs all network operations in a background thread, without blocking your main thread. Putting it in an `AsyncTask` does not give any additional benefits.

If you want to know when the write operation is finished, [`DatabaseReference.setValue(...)` returns a `Task<Void>`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)), which allows you to detect that:

```
myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).child("_id").setValue(_id).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // the write completed
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

In this case you'll probably want to combine all your writes into a single `setValue(...)` call, so that you can detect when they're *all* finished:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
values.put("_id", _id);
values.put("type", type);
values.put("message", body);
values.put("time", dateFormat.format(timestamp));
values.put("time_stamp", timestamp);

myRef.child("Chats").child(userID).child(thread_id).child(msgID).setValue(values).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // the write completed
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

If you want to learn more about `Task`s and what you can do with them, I highly recommend reading Doug Stevenson's [become a task master](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html) blog series.

Comment: I tried your method, but its not reporting the real progress, I'm uploading around 93 thousand messages, the progress bar fills instantly, but in background messages are still uploading.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine now, I was using the wrong variable for total. Thanks alot :)